# How to find a count of a combobox values

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

If I want to find the count of values in a ttk combo box how can I get that

I tried with following code statements, I am not getting the result.y please help me soon

```
countWidget=list.count(cls_Obj.boxWidget["combobox1"])

print countWidget

countWidget=cls_Obj.boxWidget["boxSolver1combobox1"].count

print countWidget
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option, `values`. Every widget has a dictionary that contains its options and values of those options.

Since I don't know your code, I can only give you a sample code which prints the count.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

cmb_values = ["item1","item2","item3","item4"]

root = tk.Tk()

cmb = ttk.Combobox(root, values = cmb_values)
cmb.pack()

#if you use cmb["values"] you will get the list of values which is cmb_values
#so to get number of items in that list, you only need len()

print len(cmb["values"])

root.mainloop()
```